# How do I solve this permutation coding question?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I remember seeing it once in Leetcode but not sure which one. Here's the problem.

I have a list `['a','b','c']`. And through permutation, I want to have a result of all kinds of possible list combinations with the give list.

**Expected**

```
result = [['a'],['b'],['c'],
          ['a','b'],['b','c'],['a','c'],
          ['a','b','c']]
```

if `['a','b','c','d']`, it should be

```
result = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],
          ['a','b'],['a','c'],['a','d'],['b','c'],['b','d'],['c','d'],
          ['a','b','c'],['a','b','d'],['a','c','d'],['b','c','d'],
          ['a','b','c','d'],
]
```

I would really appreciate if I can get any inspiration from you guys.

Comment: There is a [`powerset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe in the documentation of `itertools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to accomplish that:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

c = [list(combinations(l, i)) for i in range(1, len(l) + 1)]
```

```
>>> c
[[('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',)],
 [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')],
 [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'd')],
 [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem requires you to output the power-set of the problem, so there will always be `2^n` elements in the output, with 'n' being the number of elements in the initial list, and 2^n will include phi, so perhaps the limit for the loop will be `2^n-1`, you could try an iterative approach!

P.S. I am not giving you the answer since I feel that you want to solve this problem on your own!

Comment: Thx! I will check on that